# Oracle Apex Pie Chart SQL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, charts, oracle-apex

i'm not really much into SQL & Apex, but i need one statement and I would really appreciate your help on this.
The syntax of Apex pie charts is this:

```
SELECT link, label, value
```

My table looks like these simple sketch:

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| ID   | Company   | Item    |
+------+-----------+---------+
| 1    | AAA       |Some     |
| 2    | BB        |Stuff    |
| 3    | BB        |Not      |
| 4    | CCCC      |Important|
| 5    | AAA       |For      |
| 6    | DDDDD     |Question?|
+------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to show the percentage of the companies.

**Problem:** All companies with less than 5 items should combine to one colum "other". The difficulty for me is to combine the "unimportant" companies.

Until now my statement looks like this:

```
SELECT null link, 
company label, 
COUNT(ID) value FROM table HAVING COUNT(ID) > 5 GROUP BY company
```

Here a wonderful diagram-sketch. :D [image]

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Guys, I found the answer for my use case. Its quite similar to Ollies answer. Thanks again for the help!

```
 WITH sq1 AS (SELECT company, COUNT (*) AS count FROM 
 (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT (*) OVER  (Partition By company) > 5 THEN company
 ELSE 'other' END AS company, id FROM table) GROUP BY company)

 SELECT null link, company label, count value FROM sq1 ORDER BY count desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not got SQL Developer in front of me but this (or a close variation) should work for you:

```
WITH company_count
  AS (
      SELECT CASE
                WHEN count(*) < 5
                THEN 'Other'
                ELSE company
              END AS company_name,
             id
        FROM tablename
      ),
      company_group
  AS (
      SELECT company_name,
             count(id) item_count
        FROM company_count
       GROUP BY company_name
     )
SELECT NULL AS link,
       company_name AS label,
       item_count AS value
  FROM company_group;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! But i´m a little bit confused, from where comes the "item_count" in last SELECT statement? Respectively what information I should insert?

Comment: @OldForester I believe that `count(id)` in the company_group subquery was intended to be aliased with `item_count`. It originally was but in Ollie's second edit he likely forgot to do that so I edited it back in.

Comment: Okay I added a GROUP BY clause to the first subquery statement, because of the count function. The syntax is right, but now the diagram shows only the label "other" and the number of rows. It goes in the right direction, but one detail is still missing.